# What exactly $(Get-WmiObject win32_processor | select LoadPercentage) returns?

Tags: powershell, cpu-load

I am trying to check the Average CPU Load by using:

```
$ $($(Get-WmiObject win32_processor | select LoadPercentage).LoadPercentage) | Measure-Object -Average).Average
```

However, I am not how exactly it gets the number...

If there are 2 physical cores and 12 cores in each, does LoadPercentage returns average per Cpu, that is average per core?

Answer (score 2):

This is from my 1 CPU-socket computer. That + the quote from `Win32_Processor` documentation from MSDN below shows that it is the average percentage for the CPU (socket).

So your script will calculate the average CPU-load for the server (average for all processors, not individual cores).

```
Get-WmiObject win32_processor | select LoadPercentage

LoadPercentage
--------------
             5
```

> **LoadPercentage**
>
> Load capacity of each processor, averaged to the last second.
>   Processor loading refers to the total computing burden for each
>   processor at one time.

Source: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394373(v=vs.85).aspx)